# ERROR: URI '/checkout/cart/add/uenc/%25uenc%25/product/9495/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add)

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, error, debug

I keep seeing this error in my system error logs and not sure what it is and why this error keeps popping up? Any help on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated. We are on Magento2.3.5pt-2.

`URI '/checkout/cart/add/uenc/%25uenc%25/product/9495/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add)`

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: I have not really found a clear solution for this. We still get the error every now and then. So I am not sure what module its coming from on our store.

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently there is a piece of code somewhere on your website which makes a GET request to the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php` action in order to add items to cart.

This class implements **HttpPostActionInterface** and therefore, doesn't accept GET requests.

So my suggestion is that you investigate which are the frontend-facing implementations which would allow customers to add items to cart (I am assuming it's a customization somewhere) and overwrite that piece and transform the GET request into a POST.

Comment: Any solution to add product to cart using POST method